# How to cancel other sibling coroutines in one child coroutine in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm a new guy with kotlin coroutines.

I want to send a series requests and get the corresponding response, then wrap it to a `Map`. In the process, if one request gets a 5xx response, then I need to cancel other unfinished requests. Eventually, it should be returned a `Map` which contains the first 5xx response and all successful responses before that as the value and corresponding request as the key.

So I created multiple child async coroutines in an async coroutines to send these requests. The problem is how to cancel other sibling coroutines when one of these responses get 5xx http status code and make sure the current child coroutine still works. I tried to use `parentScope.coroutineContext.cancelChildren()`, but it will cancel current child coroutines, and I can't get the 5xx response.

Below is my code:

```
fun sendRequests(
        requestSet: Set<XxxRequest>
    ): Mono<Map<XxxRequest, XxxResponse>> =
        mono {
            // suppose there are four requests in the requestSet
            if (requestSet.isNotEmpty()) {
                val requestToResponse = async {
                    val parentScope = this
                    // suppose two of them get 200 OK, the third one get 5xx, 
                    val listDeferred = requestSet.map { request ->
                        async {     
                            downStreamService.sendRequest(request) //it's a suspend function and uses WebClient to make http call
                            .also { 
                                if (it.status.is5xxServerError) {
                                    //I want to cancel other uncompleted jobs here, and make sure the current job still works well.
                                    //Call cancelChildren() here will cancel current child Job.                                    
                                    parentScope.coroutineContext.cancelChildren() 
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // the size of responses should be 3, but in actual it's 2
                    val responses = listDeferred.filter { !it.isCancelled }.awaitAll()
                    requestSet.zip(responses).toMap()
                }
                requestToResponse.await()
            } else emptyMap()
        }
```

I also used `withContext(NonCancellable)` but it still does not work.

```
fun sendRequests(
        requestSet: Set<XxxRequest>
    ): Mono<Map<XxxRequest, XxxResponse>> =
        mono {
            if (requestSet.isNotEmpty()) {
                val requestToResponse = async {
                    val parentScope = this
                    // 
                    val listDeferred = requestSet.map { request ->
                        async {     
                            downStreamService.sendRequest(request)
                            .let { 
                                if (it.status.is5xxServerError) {
                                    //call cancelChildren() here will cancel current child Job.
                                    parentScope.coroutineContext.cancelChildren() 
                                    withContext(NonCancellable) { it } // it doesn't work.
                                } else it
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    val responses = listDeferred.filter { !it.isCancelled }.awaitAll()
                    requestSet.zip(responses).toMap()
                }
                requestToResponse.await()
            } else emptyMap()
        }
```

I'm not sure if the usage of coroutines is correct. Could anybody take a look? Thanks in advance.

---

Thanks to @Tenfour04 for the reply. Now I manually wrap the key-value into the map.

```
fun sendRequests(
        requestSet: Set<XxxRequest>
    ): Mono<Map<XxxRequest, XxxResponse>> =
        mono {
            if (requestSet.isEmpty()) return@mono emptyMap<XxxRequest, XxxResponse>()
            val mutex = Mutex()
            val resultMap = mutableMapOf<XxxRequest, XxxResponse>()
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO.limitedParallelism(4)) {
                requestSet.map { request -> 
                    launch {
                        downStreamService.sendRequest(request)
                        .let { response -> 
                            mutex.withLock {
                               resultMap += domainRQ to domainRS
                               if (domainRS.status.is5xxServerError) this@withContext.coroutineContext.cancelChildren()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }.joinAll()
            }
            resultMap
        }
```

However while I was debugging, I found that actually all the http requests had already been completed. While I got the result I wanted here, but the fact is that the remaining responses were just not packaged into the map. So, I would like to know if it is possible to cancel the requests sent to the downstream service by other coroutines when one of the tasks in multiple concurrent coroutines receives a 5xx response from the WebClient.
The `downStreamService.sendRequest(request)` like below:

```
suspend fun sendRequest(request: XxxRequest): XxxResponse =
        runCatching {
            webClient
                .put()
                .uri {
                    it.path("/xxx").build()
                }
                .body(jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(request).toMono(), String::class.java)
                .headers { addHeaders(it) }
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .awaitExchange { res ->
                    res.awaitEntity(String::class)
                        .let {
                            // parseEntityString is a non suspend function
                            parseEntityString(it.body, it.statusCodeValue)
                        }
                }
        }.getOrElse {
            val exceptionMessage = it.message
            val exceptionCause = it.cause?.message
            XxxResponse(
                status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                error = Error(exceptionMessage, exceptionCause)
                )
            )
        }
```

Comment: Is your main goal to return the 500 response if one of the requests failed, or the map if all requests succeeded?

Comment: So you want to keep all finished parallel request results up until any of them fail, then return only the successfully finished ones plus the first one that failed and stop wasting time on the rest, even if they might have succeeded? What is `downstreamService`, and is its `sendRequest` function a `suspend fun` that cooperates with cancellation?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes, I want to return the first failed response and all successful responses before that, and stop the rest jobs. The `sendRequest` function is a `suspend fun` and it uses `WebClient` to make http call.

Comment: @marstran Please refer to my previous reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you manually add the result to a map and *then* cancel, I think it would ensure the first failure gets included in the map. (I haven't tested this.) This code assumes you don't care about maintaining iteration order for your resulting map.

```
fun sendRequests(
        requestSet: Set<XxxRequest>
    ): Mono<Map<XxxRequest, XxxResponse>> =
        mono {
            if (requestSet.isEmpty()) return@mono emptyMap() // optional optimization
            val mutex = Mutex()
            val map = mutableMapOf<XxxRequest, XxxResponse>()
            requestSet.map { request ->
                launch {
                    val response = downStreamService.sendRequest(request)
                    mutex.withLock { 
                        map += request to response 
                        if (response.status.is5xxServerError) {
                            this@mono.coroutineContext.cancelChildren()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.joinAll()
            map
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me, but I'm wondering if it's possible to get the results in a non-manual way?

Comment: I don't really see how without making the code quite a bit more complicated, so what would be the point?

Comment: Thanks, but I noticed while debugging that although I got the desired result, the program didn't actually work as I expected. I updated the problem description. Could you help take a look at it if possible?